# Creating EntityManagerFactory from hibernate Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, sessionfactory

In our current application (Java SE) we use Hibernate specific API, but we kind of want to migrate to JPA wherever possible (but slowly). For that, I need `EntityManagerFactory` instead of `SessionFactory` (and I would like to keep this an axiom without dispute).

Where is the problem is, that currently our session factory is being created from `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` and I would like to keep it as it for now - as this configuration is passed thru different parts of our software which can and do configure the persistence as they want.

So the question is: how can I make

```
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                   .applySettings( hibConfiguration.getProperties() )
                                   .buildServiceRegistry();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibConfiguration.buildSessionFactory( serviceRegistry );
```

equivalent resulting in `EntityManagerFactory`?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?  What was your solution?

Comment: moving to JPA completely - it was easier than any of intermediate solutions we came up with.

Comment: Aha, so I suppose you are not using a hibernate interceptor then, right?  I have this question which does not seem to attract any answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696237/jpa-with-hibernate-5-programmatically-create-entitymanagerfactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite straightforward. You will need a `persistence.xml` though, where you have defined a persistence unit for JPA. Then you have to convert the Hibernate properties to a `Map`, so you can pass them to the  [`createEntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)) method. This will give you the `EntityManagerFactory` using your Hibernate properties.

```
public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(Configuration hibConfiguration) {
    Properties p = hibConfiguration.getProperties();

    // convert to Map
    Map<String, String> pMap = new HashMap<>();
    Enumeration<?> e = p.propertyNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String s = (String) e.nextElement();
        pMap.put(s, p.getProperty(s));
    }

    // create EntityManagerFactory
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("some persistence unit", pMap);

    return emf;
}
```

If you need the `SessionFactory` from the `EntityManagerFactory` (the other way around), then you can use this method:

```
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return ((EntityManagerFactoryImpl) entityManagerFactory).getSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: The last part should be using the unwrap() method rather than explicit casting.

Comment: I thought it works, but unfortunatelly this doesn't supply the registered entities :/ I'm doomed for persistence.xml files with entities specified :/.

Comment: That's what I meant by: *"You will need a persistence.xml though, where you have defined a persistence unit for JPA."*. You somehow have to tell JPA which entities to persist.